# tkinter NameError: name 'expression' is not defined

Tags: python, function, tkinter

i a problem with this uno calculator i had to nest it a def
but the now it won't display the equations
just keep geting
expression = expression + str(num)
NameError: name 'expression' is not defined

works perfecly when its out of a def

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def Run():
    expression = ""
    top3 = Tk() 
    top3.title("score Calqleter") 
    equation = StringVar() 
    expression_field = Entry(top3, textvariable=equation) 
    expression_field.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=70) 
    equation.set('click the cards to add') 
      
    def press(num):
        global expression
        expression = expression + str(num) 
        equation.set(expression)
    def equalpress(): 
        try: 
            global expression 
            total = str(eval(expression[:-1])) 
            equation.set(total) 
            expression = "" 
        except: 
            equation.set(" error ") 
            expression = "" 
    def clear(): 
        global expression 
        expression = "" 
        equation.set("")  
    button1 = Button(top3, text=' Card1 ', fg='black', bg='red', 
                    command=lambda: [press(1),press("+")], height=7, width=7) 
    button1.grid(row=2, column=0) 
    button2 = Button(top3, text=' Card2 ', fg='black', bg='red', 
                    command=lambda: [press(2),press("+")], height=7, width=7)  

run = Button(root, text = 'Enter Your Text', command = Run)
run.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't define funtions within other functions, and defintely don't share scope between them

Comment: `global expression` only works if you defined `expression` outside of any function (i.e. globally). Since it's only defined in `Run` then it's just accessible as a regular variable.

Comment: Also, `lambda: [press(1),press("+")]` probably isn't the best way to write what you seem to want to happen...

Comment: Try saying `expression = ''` outside all functions, in the main block. It might do some help.

Comment: Change `global expression` to `nonlocal expression`.